# Using JET OLEDB Provider, How to query headerless text file using a WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, scripting, vbscript, adodb, jet

This may be a silly question, but I can't figure out the correct syntax or if this is even possible.

I have a text file that I am querying using the Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 Provider. The text file consists is a Headerless CSV that looks somewhat like this:

```
4/11/2012 9:20:19 AM,USERID,GROUPNAME
4/12/2012 9:20:19 AM,USERID2,GROUPNAME3
4/13/2012 10:45:15 AM,USERID3,GROUPNAME2
```

I can query the entire text file with a `SELECT * FROM...` but I'd like to be able to query it on one of the columns. `SELECT * FROM myTextFile.txt WHERE column2='USERID'`

My problem is, how can I specify the column when there is no header? Is there any way to specify the second column? Something like `WHERE {1}='USERID'`

Thanks for the responses in advance!

Comment: Are you using a [schema.ini file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms709353(v=vs.85).aspx)? Try `...WHERE F2 = 'USERID'`

Comment: @onedaywhen I am not using a schema.ini file, but I am not against it. What would I need to put in there to specify F2 as the second column?

Comment: You need to include `HDR=No` in the connection string. The following article may be useful: [Much ADO About Text Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974559.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the fields are named F1, F2, F3, etc.

So in your case you can make the SQL string look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTextFile.txt WHERE F2='USERID'
```

[EDIT]  I just saw the comment from @onedaywhen...He is correct, I have used this and it works.